# Sitecore How to reference .js and .css files in

Tags: javascript, sitecore

I am writing a sample PageLayout (.cshtml) in Sitecore and I need to reference some .js and .css files.  I added the reference in the following manner

```xml
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

They are in the same folder as the .cshtml file.  However when I render the page I get the following error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `404 (Not Found)
http://url/inline.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the whole path to the css and js files.

Instead of referencing:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script>
```

use

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="/full/path/to/jsfile/inline.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this, it still says not found, what I am using now is 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Views/Drive-Sync/Carousel/styles.bundle.js"></script>
The file is in the following folder under the SiteCore web site 

Website\Views\Drive-Sync\Carousel
Website is the folder of the web site where web.config is.

Comment: You missed first `/` before `Views`. Should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Views/Drive-Sync/Carousel/styles.bundle.js"`

Comment: Still does not work I am now using
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Views/Drive-Sync/Carousel/inline.js"></script>    

My inline.js file is in the following folder
C:\inetpub\SiteCore\DefaultInstance\Website\Views\Drive-Sync\Carousel\inline.js

To add to this if I move inline.js to the root folder of the web site (C:\inetpub\SiteCore\DefaultInstance\Website) and reference it like this it works
<script type="text/javascript" src="/inline.js"></script>    

It only does not work when I move it to a subfolder.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the `-` character in the `Drive-Syc` folder name. Have you tried to move that file to any other subfolder, without `-` in the folder name?

Comment: I actually moved it to a folder outside "Views" and it worked.  so the following worked
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/main.bundle.js"></script>
However if I keep the scripts in a difference folder inside views it does not work, so the following does not work
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Views/scripts/main.bundle.js"></script>
Whats so special about this folder?

Comment: Custom `web.config` in `Views` folder blocking that file?